How to properly use composite keys as the primary key in Laravel with Spatie Roles and Permissions package?
I need to use both email and phone_number as the primary key for the User model in my Laravel application. Since Laravel doesn't natively support composite primary keys, I found a workaround to implement it. However, I'm facing issues with relationships, especially when using the Spatie Roles and Permissions package. Specifically, I'm getting an "Array to string conversion" error. Also facing issue on auth()->user() helper function which is returning unexpected result.
Here’s the setup I have:
User Model:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = ['email', 'phone_number'];
    
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'phone_number', 'name', 'password'];
}

Issue:
When accessing relationships like $user->roles, I encounter the following error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (`0` = email and `1` = phone_number) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)


laravel documentation

"Composite" Primary Keys
Eloquent requires each model to have at least one uniquely identifying "ID" that can serve as its primary key. "Composite" primary keys are not supported by Eloquent models. However, you are free to add additional multi-column, unique indexes to your database tables in addition to the table's uniquely identifying primary key.

Edit:
if you just need to let the user login with both email and phone_number the "warkaround" is pretty easy and you do not need a workaround.
this is an example using sanctum but you can easily adapt to any other auth method :
migration:
//this  migration schema is compatible (with minor changes) with sanctum
//since i don't know your auth method i based this example on sanctum
//but  you can follow the same princiles for both breeze and custom laravel auth
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('name');
  
  //if you want you can set both as index but it's not required
  $table->string('email')->unique();
  $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
  
  $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
  
  //optional but usefull if you want something like sms verification
  $table->timestamp('phone_number_verified_at')->nullable();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
  $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});

user model (i've  added some conf for phone_number and (opional) phone_number verification time):
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasTeams;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use HasTeams;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'phone_number_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }
}

App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser :
(same here it's almost untouched)
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\Team;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;

class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array<string, string>  $input
     */
    public function create(array $input): User
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            //customization
            //=================================================================
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            //==================================================================
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['accepted', 'required'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        return DB::transaction(function () use ($input) {
            return tap(User::create([
                'name' => $input['name'],
                'email' => $input['email'],
                //customization
                //=================================================================
                'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
                //=================================================================
                'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            ]), function (User $user) {
                $this->createTeam($user);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create a personal team for the user.
     */
    protected function createTeam(User $user): void
    {
        $user->ownedTeams()->save(Team::forceCreate([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => explode(' ', $user->name, 2)[0]."'s Team",
            'personal_team' => true,
        ]));
    }
}

register.blade.php:
(i put only the added html)
<div class="mt-4">
            <x-label for="phone_number" value="{{ __('Phone Number') }}" />
            <x-input id="phone_number" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="phone_number" :value="old('phone_number')" required />
        </div>

same for login.blade.php:
<!-- i change only the label and input type because this is just an example -->
        <div>
            <x-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email or Phone Number') }}" />
            <x-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autofocus autocomplete="username" />
        </div>

and now the real code, all previous is for reproduce a full testable example with laravel 11x , jetstream , sanctum template, the real custom auth code is in this file:
App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

//those are used in auth customization
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
//====================================

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);


        //this is the auth customization part:
        //===============================================================================

        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            //if i do not found user by email , i look for phone_number 
            //this ofcourse can be imporved but work smooth for this example
            if($user==null)$user = User::where('phone_number', $request->email)->first();
 
            if ($user &&
                Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                return $user;
            }
        });
        //==================================================================================
        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            $throttleKey = Str::transliterate(Str::lower($request->input(Fortify::username())).'|'.$request->ip());

            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($throttleKey);
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
    }
}


I do know Laravel doesn't have support for this, but I am trying to implement it using some workaround.

i do some edit , it seems a  lot of code but actually there are just a few lines scattered in some files
